# What kind of files or directory is expected by mongorestore when using the -d flag?

Tags: mongodb

I want to use the `mongorestore` command in a script, but I am having troubles understanding exactly what kind of input it is looking for.

After using the `mongodump` command, I end up with this tree:

```
mydirectory
└── dump
    ├── mydb1
    │   ├── schemas.bson
    │   └── schemas.metadata.json
    ├── mydb2
    │   ├── schemas.bson
    │   ├── schemas.metadata.json
    │   ├── status.bson
    │   └── status.metadata.json
    └── mydb3
        ├── schemas.bson
        └── schemas.metadata.json
```

I understood that I can use the `mongorestore` command like this:

```
mydirectory$ mongorestore
```

since it is looking by default for the `dump` directory.

However, I do not understand why using the following command:

```
mydirectory/dump$ mongorestore mydb1
```

give the following results:

```
2018-01-02T14:35:59.823+0100    building a list of dbs and collections to restore from mydb1 dir
2018-01-02T14:35:59.823+0100    don't know what to do with file "mydb1/schemas.bson", skipping...
2018-01-02T14:35:59.823+0100    don't know what to do with file "mydb1/schemas.metadata.json", skipping...
2018-01-02T14:35:59.823+0100    done
```

Moreover, when I use the `-d` flag to specify a database to restore, it only works when I specify the directory in which this database is located, for example:

```
mydirectory/dump$ mongorestore mydb1 -d mydb1
```

(I would have expected this command to work without the `-d` flag)

**What kind of files or directory is `mongorestore` expecting when using (or not) the `-d` flag?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`mongorestore` expects the `dump` folder to contain sub-folders with the database name, which in turn contain the BSON dump and the metadata. The error you're seeing is because it didn't find any subdirectory with BSON/metadata files in it.

Rather than restoring by going into the `dump` directory, it's better to use the `--nsInclude` option instead (new in MongoDB 3.4). See the [nsInclude documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongorestore/#cmdoption-nsinclude) for more details.

The option `--nsInclude` requires you to supply the namespace in the form of `<database>.<collection>`. For example, to restore the `test` database:

```
mongorestore --nsInclude "test.*"
```

To restore the `test` collection inside the `test` database:

```
mongorestore --nsInclude "test.test"
```

Make sure that you execute the restore from the `dump` directory's parent, and not from inside it.

Comment: Thanks, this is actually really helpful. However, do you know why the `-d` flag gave me the result I explained at the end of my question?

Comment: @Eldy I believe it's because the `-d` flag was designed to work from the top level directory as well. You're not expected to run `mongorestore` from inside the `dump` directory.

Comment: Thanks, running `mongorestore` in the parent directory fixed the issue for me.

Comment: thank you very much, this is what i was doing wrong