# mongorestore : don't know what to do with file "/home/path/to/folder/collection1.bson", skipping

Tags: mongodb, mongorestore

-I'm trying to import a mongodb database
- From a mongodb base **version 2.4.10** I exported the database with the command: mongodump -d DBNAME -o / path / folder
-I tried to import the dump to a mongodb engine **version 3.6.3**
-I got this error:

```html
root@server:~# mongorestore -vvvv  --nsInclude NEWDBNAME    /home/path/to/folder/
2018-04-06T10:16:35.729+0200    checking options
2018-04-06T10:16:35.734+0200            dumping with object check disabled
2018-04-06T10:16:35.734+0200    will listen for SIGTERM, SIGINT, and SIGKILL
2018-04-06T10:16:35.927+0200    connected to node type: standalone
2018-04-06T10:16:35.929+0200    standalone server: setting write concern w to 1
2018-04-06T10:16:35.929+0200    using write concern: w='1', j=false, fsync=false, wtimeout=0
2018-04-06T10:16:35.929+0200    mongorestore target is a directory, not a file
2018-04-06T10:16:35.929+0200    preparing collections to restore from
2018-04-06T10:16:35.929+0200    using /home/path/to/folder/ as dump root directory
2018-04-06T10:16:35.952+0200    don't know what to do with file "/home/path/to/folder/collection1.bson", skipping...
2018-04-06T10:16:35.952+0200    don't know what to do with file "/home/path/to/folder/collection1.metadata.json", skipping...
2018-04-06T10:16:35.952+0200    don't know what to do with file "/home/path/to/folder/collection2.bson", skipping...
2018-04-06T10:16:35.953+0200    don't know what to do with file "/home/path/to/folder/collection2.metadata".json", skipping...
2018-04-06T10:16:35.953+0200    don't know what to do with file "/home/path/to/folder/collection3.bson", skipping...
2018-04-06T10:16:35.953+0200    don't know what to do with file "/home/path/to/folder/collection3.metadata".json", skipping...
2018-04-06T10:16:35.953+0200    don't know what to do with file "/home/path/to/folder/collectionX.bson", skipping...
2018-04-06T10:16:35.953+0200    don't know what to do with file "/home/path/to/folder/collectionX.metadata.json", skipping...
.
.
.
2018-04-06T10:16:35.958+0200    finalizing intent manager with multi-database longest task first prioritizer
2018-04-06T10:16:35.958+0200    restoring up to 4 collections in parallel
2018-04-06T10:16:35.958+0200    starting restore routine with id=3
2018-04-06T10:16:35.958+0200    ending restore routine with id=3, no more work to do
2018-04-06T10:16:35.958+0200    starting restore routine with id=0
2018-04-06T10:16:35.958+0200    ending restore routine with id=0, no more work to do
2018-04-06T10:16:35.958+0200    starting restore routine with id=1
2018-04-06T10:16:35.958+0200    ending restore routine with id=1, no more work to do
2018-04-06T10:16:35.959+0200    starting restore routine with id=2
2018-04-06T10:16:35.959+0200    ending restore routine with id=2, no more work to do
2018-04-06T10:16:35.959+0200    done
```

Note: Result with other command

```html
root@server:~# mongorestore -vvv  -d  NEWDBName  /home/tmp/path/folder/
2018-04-06T10:47:22.949+0200    checking options
2018-04-06T10:47:22.951+0200            dumping with object check disabled
2018-04-06T10:47:22.954+0200    will listen for SIGTERM, SIGINT, and SIGKILL
2018-04-06T10:47:22.963+0200    connected to node type: standalone
2018-04-06T10:47:22.963+0200    standalone server: setting write concern w to 1
2018-04-06T10:47:22.963+0200    using write concern: w='1', j=false, fsync=false, wtimeout=0
**2018-04-06T10:47:22.963+0200    the --db and --collection args should only be used when restoring from a BSON file. Other uses are deprecated and will not exist in the future; use --nsInclude instead**
2018-04-06T10:47:22.963+0200    mongorestore target is a directory, not a file
2018-04-06T10:47:22.963+0200    building a list of collections to restore from /home/tmp/path/folder dir
2018-04-06T10:47:22.963+0200    reading collections for database DBNAME in folder
2018-04-06T10:47:22.963+0200    found collection DBNAME.collectionX bson to restore to DBNAME.collectionX
2018-04-06T10:47:22.963+0200    found collection metadata from DBNAME.collectionX to restore to DBNAME.collectionX
2018-04-06T10:47:22.963+0200    found collection DBNAME.collectionY bson to restore to DBNAME.collectionY
2018-04-06T10:47:22.963+0200    found collection metadata from DBNAME.collectionY to restore to DBNAME.collectionY
2018-04-06T10:47:22.963+0200    found collection DBNAME.collectionZ bson to restore to DBNAME.collectionZ
2018-04-06T10:47:22.963+0200    found collection metadata from DBNAME.collectionZ to restore to DBNAME.collectionZ
.
.
.

2018-04-06T10:47:22.964+0200    not restoring system.indexes collection because database DBNAME has .metadata.json files
2018-04-06T10:47:22.964+0200    found collection DBNAME.system.users bson to restore to DBNAME.system.users
2018-04-06T10:47:22.964+0200    found collection metadata from DBNAME.system.users to restore to DBNAME.system.users
2018-04-06T10:47:22.964+0200    found collection DBNAME.typeincidents bson to restore to DBNAME.typeincidents
2018-04-06T10:47:22.964+0200    found collection metadata from DBNAME.typeincidents to restore to DBNAME.typeincidents
.
.
.
2018-04-06T10:47:22.964+0200    finalizing intent manager with multi-database longest task first prioritizer
2018-04-06T10:47:22.964+0200    restoring up to 4 collections in parallel
2018-04-06T10:47:22.964+0200    starting restore routine with id=3
2018-04-06T10:47:22.964+0200    starting restore routine with id=0
2018-04-06T10:47:22.964+0200    starting restore routine with id=1
2018-04-06T10:47:22.964+0200    starting restore routine with id=2
2018-04-06T10:47:22.964+0200    reading metadata for DBNAME.evenements from /home/tmp/path/folder/evenements.metadata.json
2018-04-06T10:47:22.964+0200    creating collection DBNAME.evenements using options from metadata
2018-04-06T10:47:22.964+0200    using collection options: bson.D{bson.DocElem{Name:"create", Value:"evenements"}, bson.DocElem{Name:"idIndex", Value:mongorestore.IndexDocument{Options:bson.M{"name":"_id_", "ns":"DBNAME.evenements"}, Key:bson.D{bson.DocElem{Name:"_id", Value:1}}, PartialFilterExpression:bson.D(nil)}}}
2018-04-06T10:47:22.965+0200    Failed: DBNAME.evenements: error creating collection DBNAME.evenements: error running create command: BSON field 'OperationSessionInfo.create' is a duplicate field
```

**Thank you for help**

Answer (score 1):

mongorestore expects the dump folder to contain sub-folders with the database name, which in turn contain the BSON dump and the metadata. The error you're seeing is because it didn't find any subdirectory with BSON/metadata files in it.

For Example in your case

```
mongorestore -vvvv  --nsInclude NEWDBNAME    /home/path/to/folder/
```

You should use below command

```
mongorestore -vvvv  --nsInclude NEWDBNAME    /home/path/to/
```

where "folder" will be the name of the directory containing the database name dump directory and inside it should have the bson files

Refer below link

[Stack Overflow Question Answered on Don't know what to do with file “/”, skipping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48062082/what-kind-of-files-or-directory-is-expected-by-mongorestore-when-using-the-d-fl)